# Down Sample Resolution Change Band Sum

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I collected information from `WorldPop` about the Italian population in `2000` that is a `geoTiff` with a spatial resolution of `100m`. The data can be downloaded [here](https://www.worldpop.org/).

I would like to change the resolution at `300m` and save as `netCDF`. This is what I am doing:

```
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.Translate('ita_ppp_2000.nc', 'ita_ppp_2000.tif', format='NetCDF')
```

The issue is that if I sum the population from the original file I have the following:

```
fn = 'ita_ppp_2000.nc'
pop = dse.Band1.values
np.sum(pop[pop>0])
56780870.0
```

If I change the resolution in this way the sum of the `Band1` is `5132553.0` instead of `56780870.0`

```
gdal.Warp('ita_ppp_2000_rescaled.nc', 'ita_ppp_2000.nc', xRes=0.002778, yRes=0.002778, format='NetCDF')
fn = 'ita_ppp_2000_rescaled.nc'
dse = xr.open_dataset(fn)
pop = dse.Band1.values
np.sum(pop[pop>0])
5132553.0
```

Comment: A difference makes sense to me. For example, if you turn three pixels (100x100) and turn them into one pixel (300x300) that one pixel will have an average value of the three. `Pixel 1=10`, `pixel 2=20`, `pixel 3=30`, `Sum=60`.  `Pixel 123=20`, `Sum=20`.

Comment: You could try `gdalwarp` with `-r sum`: https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-r